# Python: Breadth First Search capable of returning largest distance?

Tags: python, dictionary, breadth-first-search

I have a dictionary representing a directed graph. For example...

```
myDict = {'foo': ['hello', 'stack'], 'bar' : ['over', 'flow']}
```

This means that the **'foo'** node points to **'hello'** and **'stack'** while the **'bar'** node points to **'over'** and **'flow'**.

I have also written code for performing a breadth first search to find the *shortest* path between any two nodes...

```
from collections import deque

def breadthFirstSearch(graph, start, end):
    q = deque()
    path = (start, )
    q.append(path)
    visited = set([start])
    while q:
        path = q.popleft()
        last_node = path[-1]
        if last_node == end:
            return path
        for node in graph[last_node]:
            if node not in visited:
                visited.add(node)
                q.append(path + (node,))
    print 'There is no path from ' + start + ' to ' + end + '.'
    return None
```

My question is: Is it possible to modify this breadth first search so as it gives me the largest shortest path and the start and end nodes for that path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is called the "graph diameter problem."

Breadth-first search creates a breadth-first search tree.  The longest tree path between two nodes is, in general, going to be longer than the longest path between them because of the presence of non-tree edges.  So no, you can't get BFS to do that directly.

BFS will nail it for trees, but it's slightly nontrivial.

There's a variant called "lexicographic breadth-first search" that can find the diameter of some restricted classes of graphs.  Those graph classes that I've run into where LBFS works tended to look a lot like trees.

EDIT:  You can, of course, run BFS once starting from each node and figure out the longest of the paths that BFS reports.  Or you could use the extremely elegant [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was thinking of just doing a breadth first search for every possible combination of nodes and selecting the longest lengthed path. But I have 100000+ nodes and it takes too long so it doesnt run. Is there anyway to run this brute force method faster?

Comment: How dense is your graph?  Does it have any special structure?  Heck, what is your graph?

Comment: My graph is as described above. Its just a dictionary where every key is a node and its values are the nodes that the node connects to. It consist of about 100000+ nodes in total. (Its a directed graph too)

Comment: @Clay:  Well, no; your graph isn't described above.  Where did the nodes and edges come from?  What do they mean?  You have to realise that you probably aren't going to get a general-purpose algorithm that runs acceptably fast on a graph that big; you need to do tailor something to the problem at hand.

Comment: In that case, I dont know where the nodes and edges come from. But my breadth First Search is working. So I dont know.